# Please add tags to answers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, api, tags, answers

Update:  This was completed as of [API version 2.1](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/change-log).

---

When querying any API method which returns answers (`/users/ids/answers`, `/answers/ids`, etc.) the result does not include the tag information for the related question.

The API does not support filtering answers by tag, but querying for a user's answers is a relatively inexpensive operation for all but the most prolific users. These can subsequently be filtered/sorted without need for additional API calls if the tag data were included for each answer result.

I feel this would add great value to the data without needing to pull all the questions.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm... this is an interesting problem.

Just going off of usage statistics, nearly everybody is grabbing answers as part of `/questions/{id}` or `/questions`.  This strongly suggests that what use of `*/answers` there is, is largely independent of corresponding question (if I had to guess, I'd say its generally user analytics of some sort).

However, one of the points of `*/answers` is to allow for an optimization in which you skip the corresponding `*/questions` call.  Obviously this doesn't work if you want to keep tags in sync.

This is very much "on the margin," ultimately.  If better response filtering schemes pan out in a subsequent API version, this will probably be done; if not it probably won't.

In other words, I'd say returning `tags` on an answer is a waste of bandwidth in the common case but there's a sufficiently valid use case such that an optional return has merit.  I'm putting this on the "re-evaluate at a later date" list.

Comment: Consider that I am interactively scrutinizing a particular user and I want to examine their answers. The only vector for user specific answers is /users/id/answers which contains a question stub giving me the context I need to determine if I am interested in pulling the question.. with the exception of the tags. While analytics would be a valid use case, I have a real world case of interactive browsing and the inclusion of tags in the stub would economize the case of browsing a user's answers.

Comment: So, in this case, which will become more common i am sure, the inclusion of a few more bytes in the question stub compared to servicing additional request on /questions would result in significantly  less bandwith overall.

Comment: I'd like to make a stronger case for including tags for each answer. Anybody attempting to do user analytics (as you've correctly divined) then has to perform N vectorized calls to /questions/ids, which is bounded by URL length, not number of IDs—an incredibly brittle solution that wastes a ton of API calls and bandwidth just to get a short list of tags.

IOW, providing tags (even as an optional return) is a valuable bit of information about an answer, and punches above its weight in terms of bandwidth & API request savings. Please reconsider and add this feature!